# Lodash omit by value in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array

```
var arrIn = [
    { 'a': 'a-0', 'b': 'b-0', 'c': 'c-0' },
    { 'a': 'a-1', 'b': 'b-1', 'c': 'c-1' },
    { 'a': 'a-2', 'b': 'b-2', 'c': 'c-2' }
];
```

I need to remove the item `arrIn.a === 'a-1'` with `lodash` and have

```
var arrOut = [
    { 'a': 'a-0', 'b': 'b-0', 'c': 'c-0' },
    { 'a': 'a-2', 'b': 'b-2', 'c': 'c-2' }
];
```

How to do it with Lodash `_.omit()` or `_.omitBy()`?

Comment: You can also do this with just the standard [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `arrIn.filter(element => element.a !== 'a-1')`

Answer (score 4):

A solution is not complicated, but sometimes it takes some time to find it. You are going to use _.omitBy() and then to transform the object into an array with Object.values():

```
var arrIn = [
    { 'a': 'a-0', 'b': 'b-0', 'c': 'c-0' },
    { 'a': 'a-1', 'b': 'b-1', 'c': 'c-1' },
    { 'a': 'a-2', 'b': 'b-2', 'c': 'c-2' }
];

var arrOut = _.omitBy(arrIn, {'a': 'a-1'});     
    arrOut = Object.values(arrOut);

console.info('_omit:',{arrIn: arrIn, arrOut:arrOut});
```

You have in console =>

```
[
    { 'a': 'a-0', 'b': 'b-0', 'c': 'c-0' },
    { 'a': 'a-2', 'b': 'b-2', 'c': 'c-2' }
];
```

Comment: Why do that when you can achieve exactly the same thing with `arrIn.filter(item => item['a'] !== 'a-1')`?

Comment: You are right, there are different ways to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

With an array like this, you can also use the lodash `_.filter` method, or the native Array `.filter` method if available (not supported on older browsers).

Example of both:

```js
var arrIn = [
    { 'a': 'a-0', 'b': 'b-0', 'c': 'c-0' },
    { 'a': 'a-1', 'b': 'b-1', 'c': 'c-1' },
    { 'a': 'a-2', 'b': 'b-2', 'c': 'c-2' }
];

// Using Lodash:
var lodashResult = _.filter(arrIn, function(item) { return item.a !== "a-1"; });
console.log("Lodash:", lodashResult);

// Using built-in filter method and es6 arrow syntax:
var filterResult = arrIn.filter(item => item.a !== "a-1");
console.log("Built-in filter:", filterResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```